# I cannot understand why text align isn't working

Tags: html, css

I cannot understand what is happening with this.  This is some html code and some CSS, and the "wonderland world" text is like 20 pixels to the right, and not the center.  Does anyone know the reason for this?

**Image of webpage:**
[image: image of webpage]

```css
.TopBorder {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.NameOfMovie {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="TopBorder">
  <p class="NameOfMovie">the wonderland world</p>
</div>
<div class="subMainContainer">
  {{>newPost}}
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to paste as much code as possible for people to help, since the current code you gave here could't reproduce your situation, here is my codepen after pasting your code: https://codepen.io/louielyl/pen/vYdVeQw

Comment: From the picture, the text is placed in the center of the body! But 'red' box not placed in the center.

Comment: You are showing us code for the name of the movie, which is centered OK but you haven't shown us all the code for the rest (the red box) and it's that that isn't centered.